# jQuery/JavaScript - Hide all elements with IDs and leave all others

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am developing a catalog page for products. Every product has a specific `div` element with an id. For example:

```
<div id="2354234" class="product">Here is name, image and description of the product</div>
<div id="2354235" class="product">Here is name, image and description of the product</div>
<div id="2354236" class="product">Here is name, image and description of the product</div>
<div id="2354237" class="product">Here is name, image and description of the product</div>
<div id="2354238" class="product">Here is name, image and description of the product</div>
<div id="2354239" class="product">Here is name, image and description of the product</div>
<div id="2354240" class="product">Here is name, image and description of the product</div>
<div id="2354241" class="product">Here is name, image and description of the product</div>
<div id="2354242" class="product">Here is name, image and description of the product</div>
<div id="2354243" class="product">Here is name, image and description of the product</div>
```

And these products are loaded with PHP getting them from a MySQL database. At the end of the page I have pagination. Only 10 products are shown per page. All products are 300, so I have 30 pages with 10 products per page.

How can I make the page update when a user clicks a button in real time without reloading to hide all other elements except 6 for example with specific ids.

Can you help me out with any advice? I can work very well with jQuery and PHP so I need a suggestion how this thing may be accomplished.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried with ajax??

Comment: I'd definitely recommend controlling pagination with AJAX and PHP rather than just toggling items in JavaScript. It'll be save resources and you won't need to worry about limiting to 300 products. Just google "PHP AJAX Pagination" and you'll get lots of tutorials. Here's an example: http://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-jquery-ajax-php/

Answer (score 1):

Using the [CSS attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) should do it:

```
$('div[id]').not('#2354234,#2354235,#2354236').hide();
```